# Get Distinct records based on column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns in a table where column A has distinct records and column b does not i.e. column b could have multiple items of the same value in each row.

What I require is to only show distinct records based on column B.  I do need both columns though as it will be an input in Crystal Reports but I don't care what value column A has.

CreatedBy column has multiple different values and I need to get those distinct values.

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT nh.InNeoHistoryId,  nh.CreatedBy
FROM NeoHistory nh
GROUP BY nh.CreatedBy, nh.InNeoHistoryId
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: So what's wrong with that result? They look Distinct to me.

Comment: Its column CreatedBy that I need distinct.  And whatever the top/first related value of the first column is. Manager is showing up multiple times, I just need manager showing once.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY nh.CreatedBy only. Use MIN or MAX for the id.

Comment: you cannot read the first column as it is. You should use aggregate function for column 1.

Comment: @jarlh, exactly what I needed.  You can post an answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Too late to be answered, since it has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
SELECT nh.CreatedBy,min(nh.InNeoHistoryId)
FROM NeoHistory nh group by nh.CreatedBy
```

Comment: Yes this works.  But I need the top/first related value of the first column.  If that makes sense. I.e. I need both column where column B is distinct and column A shows the top/first related value it finds against column B.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric, modified the answer - you can check now

Comment: Yup - thats it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a small tweak to your query:

```
SELECT MIN(nh.InNeoHistoryId), nh.CreatedBy
FROM NeoHistory nh
GROUP BY nh.CreatedBy
```